# Multiple web-apps in Tomcat by hostname sub-directory issue

Tags: tomcat

I have created a folder called **webappsx** under Tomcat folder and added a file called **sample.war** in it.

I have this entry in server.xml:

```
<Host name="otherhost"  appBase="webappsx" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" />
```

And I have also edited my hosts file so that I could test in my local.

When I go to

```
http://otherhost:8081/sample/
```

I see the application running fine. Up to here it is all good. But I want to be able to see the application when I visit

```
http://otherhost:8081
```

So what I am trying is:

```
<Host name="otherhost"  appBase="webappsx/sample" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" />
```

But this does not seem to work. A "Not Found" is returned from the server. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy the application in the ROOT directory. Call the file ROOT.war before deployment and use:

```
<Host name="otherhost"  appBase="webappsx" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" />
```